# Parse JSON from file using Codable swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have JSON file with cities

```
[
{"country":"UA","name":"Hurzuf","_id":707860,"coord":{"lon":34.283333,"lat":44.549999}},
{"country":"RU","name":"Novinki","_id":519188,"coord":{"lon":37.666668,"lat":55.683334}},
{"country":"NP","name":"Gorkhā","_id":1283378,"coord":{"lon":84.633331,"lat":28}},
{"country":"IN","name":"State of Haryāna","_id":1270260,"coord":{"lon":76,"lat":29}},
{"country":"UA","name":"Holubynka","_id":708546,"coord":{"lon":33.900002,"lat":44.599998}},
{"country":"NP","name":"Bāgmatī Zone","_id":1283710,"coord":{"lon":85.416664,"lat":28}},
{"country":"RU","name":"Mar’ina Roshcha","_id":529334,"coord":{"lon":37.611111,"lat":55.796391}},
{"country":"IN","name":"Republic of India","_id":1269750,"coord":{"lon":77,"lat":20}},
{"country":"NP","name":"Kathmandu","_id":1283240,"coord":{"lon":85.316666,"lat":27.716667}},
{"country":"UA","name":"Laspi","_id":703363,"coord":{"lon":33.733334,"lat":44.416668}},
{"country":"VE","name":"Merida","_id":3632308,"coord":{"lon":-71.144997,"lat":8.598333}},
{"country":"RU","name":"Vinogradovo","_id":473537,"coord":{"lon":38.545555,"lat":55.423332}},
{"country":"IQ","name":"Qarah Gawl al ‘Ulyā","_id":384848,"coord":{"lon":45.6325,"lat":35.353889}},
{"country":"RU","name":"Cherkizovo","_id":569143,"coord":{"lon":37.728889,"lat":55.800835}},
{"country":"UA","name":"Alupka","_id":713514,"coord":{"lon":34.049999,"lat":44.416668}},
{"country":"DE","name":"Lichtenrade","_id":2878044,"coord":{"lon":13.40637,"lat":52.398441}},
{"country":"RU","name":"Zavety Il’icha","_id":464176,"coord":{"lon":37.849998,"lat":56.049999}},
{"country":"IL","name":"‘Azriqam","_id":295582,"coord":{"lon":34.700001,"lat":31.75}},
{"country":"IN","name":"Ghūra","_id":1271231,"coord":{"lon":79.883331,"lat":24.766666}}
]
```

These are only few entries, I have almost 1000 entries into file.
I need to apply pagination to load 100 entries.

I created `codable` as follows

```
struct Cities: Codable {
    let city: [City]?
    let pagination: Pagination?
}

struct City: Codable{
    let country : String
    let name : String
    let _id : Int
    let coord: [Coordinates]?
}

struct Coordinates: Codable {
    let lat : Double?
    let lon : Double?
}

struct Pagination: Codable {
    let limit, offset: Int?
}
```

and my parsing method is like this,

```
func getDataFrom(completion: @escaping (Cities?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cities", withExtension: "json")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        do {
            let jsonDescription = try JSONDecoder().decode(Cities.self, from: data)
            print(jsonDescription)
            completion(jsonDescription,nil)
        }
        catch let jsonError {
            print("Json Error:", jsonError)
        }
    }
```

When I parse the data it goes into catch block and gives this error

```
Json Error: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.
I need to parse this data and show on tableview with pagination.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can’t make up your own types that doesn’t exist in the json. Use `JSONDecoder().decode([City].self,…)` instead and then if you want to you can create an instance of `Cities` and add the decoded result to that instance.

Comment: I tried that too
gives this error :- Json Error: typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "coord", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Given the previous error that I helped you with, doesn't the error message tell you anything?

Comment: Yea, I have tried such mechanism before as well, but considering data I don't understand what's issue this is giving me now. here

Comment: You should put your JSON in app.quicktype.io and use the structures generated by it. Also I wouldn't worry about pagination with 1000 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to decode a type of `Cities.self`, but your JSON is an array - it starts with "[" and ends with "]". You might want to try declaring the type `[Cities].self` in your decoder call.

```
let jsonDescription = try JSONDecoder().decode([City].self, from: data)
```

**Edit:**

@Joakim_Danielson caught an issue, you need to decode the array `[City]` and not `[Cities]`, because that's what your JSON is (I edited the above line of code accordingly).

But there is another issue: the property `coord` in your struct `City` is declared as an array `[Coordinates]?`, but your JSON does not have an array in the "coord" key - just a single instance.

Try changing your `coord` property, make it a type of `Coordinate?`.

Comment: :- I tried that too, when I do the same, no error comes up but parsing doesn't get any data. It print like this. Cities(city: nil, pagination: nil)

Comment: I just edited my answer, I saw another issue that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple Code Custom JSON Data Parsing with Codable & Clean code with generic in swift & Single responsibility principle (SRP) Swift -> More Help Full

let urlProduct = "https://dummyjson.com/products/"

```
// MARK: - Products
struct Products: Codable {
    let products: [Product]?
    let total, skip, limit: Int?
}

// MARK: - Product
struct Product: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let title, description: String?
    let price: Int?
    let discountPercentage, rating: Double?
    let stock: Int?
    let brand, category: String?
    let thumbnail: String?
    let images: [String]?
}

class HttpsHandler{
    func getApiData<T: Codable>(url: URL, requestType: T.Type, completionHandler: @escaping(_ result: T?) -> Void){
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, URLResponse, error in
                do{
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data!)
                    completionHandler(result)
                }catch{
                    print("error decode json")
                }
        }.resume()
    }
}

class ProductClass {
    let _httpsHandler: HttpsHandler
    
    init(_httpsHandler: HttpsHandler) {
        self._httpsHandler = _httpsHandler
    }
    func getProductData() -> Void{
        _httpsHandler.getApiData(url: URL(string: urlProduct)!, requestType: Products.self) { result in
            if let productsResult = result{
                if let products = productsResult.products{
                    for produts in products {
                        print(produts.title ?? "")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

let product = ProductClass(_httpsHandler: HttpsHandler())
product.getProductData()
```